# How to write single slash in string programmatically

Tags: string-manipulation, unicode

Consider the function:

```
unicode[numericLetters_List]:=StringJoin@Reverse@Cases[numericLetters,x_:>If[x!=" ","\:"<>x,x]];
```

now

```
unicode[{"06af", "0648", "0644"}]
```

prints `"\\:0644\\:0648\\:06af"`

instead of `"\:0644\:0648\:06af"`

How do i fix this?

Comment: Actually, you have already obtained what you desire, to see which, run `unicode[{"06af", "0648", "0644"}] // FullForm`.

Comment: Actually it still shows `\\:` while `\:` would have converted the successive characters into a corresponding Unicode character.

Comment: Then I **GUESS** this is what you want: `FromCharacterCode[FromDigits[#, 16]] & /@ Reverse @ {"06af", "0648", "0644"}`. You may use `StringJoin` afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you might want to get the characters to be shown, then you might need `FromCharacterCode`. So I suggest to define your `unicode` function in this way:

```
unicode[code_List] := FromCharacterCode[FromDigits[#, 16]] & /@ Reverse@code // StringJoin

unicode[{"06af", "0648", "0644"}]
```

> ```
> "لوگ"
> ```